# Nexus 7 refuses to pair with in car audio?

Tags: nexus-7, 4.4-kitkat, bluetooth-audio

I have a Nexus 7 running Android 4.4 and an in car stereo unit (Alpine CDE-178BT). I have enabled bluetooth on both devices but they refuse to pair with each other.

If I attempt to initiate the pairing using the Nexus 7, it starts connecting, I am prompted to allow the device to pair on the Alpine unit, but upon allowing the pairing to take place on the Alpine unit, the device drops into the "paired" list on the Nexus 7 but doesn't connect. Subsequent attempts to connect by tapping on the car stereo in the bluetooth paired devices list on the Nexus 7 resumes in a momentary attempt to connect and then the entry resetting back to its "paired but not doing anything" state.

If I attempt to initiate the pairing using the Alpine CDE-178BT, after making the Nexus 7 temporarily visible and searching for bluetooth devices using the Alpine unit, I see an entry for the Nexus 7 but any attempt to pair with it just results in a generic "Failed" message on the car stereo.

The car stereo works fine for connecting to an iPhone/iPad/other iOS device and older (pre version 4) Android devices, it is just Android devices running a more recent version of Android that it experiences issues with.

What steps can I take to attempt to resolve this issue?

Answer (score -1):

I dont know which nexus 7 Gen you are using, but IMO there must be an incompatibility between the tablet's and car's bluetooth technology.

Comment: This hardly helps the OP does it?